# how to use the EventOrder attribute in fullcalendar jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I would like to use the eventOrder attribute for the fullcalendar jquery plugin but I can't find any examples how to set the property.
I added non-standard field property, description, that I would like to use.
How do you set this property to the eventOrder?
This is how my events currently display:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: {month: 'MMMM'},   
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',
            // data: "{'userID':'" + $('#<%= hidUserID.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",  //this is what I use to pass who's calendar it is
            //completely take out 'data:' line if you don't want to pass to webmethod - Important to also change webmethod to not accept any parameters
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];                     
                $(doc).each(function () { 
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                        start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        description: $(this).attr('description')
                    });

                });
                callback(events);
                } ,                                                                   
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error fetching events!")
            }
        });
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
    },
    //this is the problem...how to set the eventOrder?
    eventOrder: ["description"]
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that you're using [FullCalendar v.2.4](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)

Then, you need to remove the brackets "[ ]" around "description".

```
eventOrder: "description"
```

Check this fiddle, where I sorted by title descending: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/waa23ry0/

Comment: I am using V 2.4.  The fiddle page returned a 404 error.  But I will try your suggestion.

Comment: It still does not work.  I change the name of the descriptions so the order should change and it is not affected.  I also tried using 'title' to sort by and it does not change the event order

Comment: My apologies for the link, I had several JS opened and I copy-pasted the wrong one. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/waa23ry0/

Comment: That worked.  Maybe the eventOrder needs to be before I define the events.  Let me try that.

Comment: That did not work.  But my events are longer than 1 day. They are 7 days long.  They do not start and stop on the same day.  Is this a problem?

Comment: Defining the orderEvent parameter before or after assigning the events give the same result with me.
I have update the fiddle, adding a description as well : http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/waa23ry0/1/

Comment: Yes, it is definately a problem: `Determines the vertical ordering events that have the same dates / times.`
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/

Comment: Yes.  I missed that in the documentation...'same date and time'.  OK.  Thanks for your help.  I will just have to use color to distinguish between groups, not order.